# how to treat var in second multiprocessing.Pool when the var is from first Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

How to treat var in second multiprocessing.Pool when the var is from first Pool?

For the example code

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd 

lst = [1, 2, 3]

def csv(code):
    df = pd.DataFrame({code: [code, code**2, code**3]}, index=lst)
    return {code: df}

def mp1():
    with Pool(8) as pool:
        rs = pool.map(csv, lst)
        dfs = dict((key, val) for k in rs for key, val in k.items())
        return dfs 

def dosomthing(code):
    dfs[code] = dfs[code] * code
    return {code: dfs[code]}

def mp_dosomething():
    with Pool(8) as pool:
        rs = pool.map(dosomthing, lst)
        dfc = dict((key, val) for k in rs for key, val in k.items())
        return dfc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dfs = mp1()
    dfc = mp_dosomething()
```

I can easily get dfs after `if __name__ == '__main__':` from fuction mp1.

But when I want to do something with dfs using second Pool.

It will get errer:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NeNe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\NeNe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "c:\Users\NeNe\OneDrive\Python\test.py", line 17, in dosomthing
    dfs[code] = dfs[code] * code
NameError: name 'dfs' is not defined
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\NeNe\OneDrive\Python\test.py", line 28, in <module>
    dfc = mp_dosomething()
  File "c:\Users\NeNe\OneDrive\Python\test.py", line 22, in mp_dosomething
    rs = pool.map(dosomthing, lst)
  File "C:\Users\NeNe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 367, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\NeNe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 774, in get
    raise self._value
NameError: name 'dfs' is not defined
```

How can I get the dfc?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question. Probably you are mixing up local and global variables.

Comment: I add global dfs and global dfc, but it's not work too.

Comment: The "dfs" variable doesn't exist in the worker processes. The "Pool" constructor has parameters "initializer" and "initargs" to transmit the "dfs" data. The initializer function can then set the "dfs" variable with received data in the worker processes.

Comment: Sorry but it's hard to understand to me. Could you write example code to show how to get dfc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least on Windows, global variables of the main process are not available in the worker processes. The Pool class supports to call an initializer function on each worker to receive such variables (if their data can be pickled) and set them.

Here this can be done like:

```
def initializer(ext_dfs):
    global dfs
    dfs = ext_dfs


def mp_dosomething():
    with Pool(8, initializer, (dfs,)) as pool:
        # Do work
```